# Visual Studio Code - open git editor in new workspace

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In my local `.gitconfig`, I can easily set my git editor to Visual Studio Code.

```
[core]
  editor = code --wait
```

This opens the editor in the current workspace. Is there any way to configure it to open in a new workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `-new-window` flag will do the trick. [(Casually mentioned here)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: It would not say it is not documented. `code --help` lists it.

Comment: Yep, this did it. Thanks.